# auto updating software on cloud

Tags: google-app-engine, open-source, cloud

I know wordpress,joomla,drupal etc ( most of php_mysql stack ) can auto detect update in software itself or/and plugin and either ask for user permission to update or auto update it.

How to do similar thing on google app engine like cloud computing ?

I am creating an open source software which is targeted towards non-computer people. who can not clone my code and update their application easily.

what is the easier way to do this ?

Comment: Are you hosting this app yourself, or allow users to install it on their own Google App Engine app?

Comment: Allow user to host on their own app, that way not only i don't have to worry about database and bandwidth usage, complexity drastically reduces and security increases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it's technically possible for an app to re-deploy itself, implementing this functionality would be difficult, and may be contrary to the Terms of Service, too.

If you want non-technical users to use your app, your best option is to provide it as a Software-as-a-Service app - eg, a single instance that users pay for access to, and which supports multi-tenancy - and update it yourself.